# How to call a public void from a private class

Tags: java

So i'm trying to make a rock paper scissors game for school and the teacher doesnt help me or answer my questions, so if someone can help me that would be great

so i need to disable the buttons after the user has pressed them and i have done so like this:

```
public void TurnOffButtons()
{
myRock.disable();
myScissors.disable();
myPaper.disable();
}
```

myRock, myPaper and myScissors are the button names

i have 3 different private classes, which run whenever the user presses the buttons, and i want to call the method TurnOffButtons in these classes to temporarily disable them so that the user cannot keep pressing them before pressing new game where the buttons are then re enabled (this prevents the user from continuously winning)

my question is how do i call them? i tried using this line of code:

```
new TurnOffButtons();
```

but it gave me an error 
if anyone could help that would be amazing

Comment: You need to call `TurnOffButtons` on an instance of the class that it's in. So something like `yourObject.TurnOffButtons()`

Comment: And you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: method names always start with lowercase.

Comment: @Ethan As tips to tag onto MC Emperor. Always add a layer of tabbing with braces, so that it looks like [this](http://nickgravgaard.com/elastic-tabstops/images/columnblocks_coloured.gif). Additionally, do not post on StackOverflow with "gave me an error". _What_ error? Copy paste it so that we can see.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an object `obj` with a method `foo`, then the syntax for executing that function is `obj.foo()`. Simply write `obj.TurnOffButtons()`. If the function calling `TurnOffButtons` is inside of the same class that defined `TurnOffButtons`, then you can just write `TurnOffButtons();` without using any `obj`.

I don't think this is your question though, since by writing `new TurnOffButtons()`, it's clear that there is a misunderstanding of what "object" and "function" mean, and thus I find that my previous paragraph will probably not help you. These ideas are critical for being able to understand Java code. Please read or watch tutorials on the internet/YouTube, so you understand the language. Then, try writing in the language, by practicing with the console/terminal. You're not going to be able to finish an interactive UI at this level. That doesn't mean you can't learn - it's not that hard, but, you will have to learn first.

Comment: thanks for your reply... i just started coding java so i'm not that experienced yet, and therefore sometimes get confused since theres a lot of things to keep in mind. thanks for your reply!